# Minecraft ModLoader mod, problems with private field netManager

Tags: java, minecraft

So, I've been making a mod for Minecraft, where I need to check the server IP. I currently have the code in place, but I am getting a NoSuchFieldException because it's a private field from another class. I am using ModLoaders getPrivateValue which uses reflection. I would rather not uses private values, and it needs to stay private.
Here's the problem code:

```
public boolean isMCMEServer(EntityClientPlayerMP player) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    NetworkManager manager = (NetworkManager) ModLoader.getPrivateValue(NetClientHandler.class, player.sendQueue, "netManager");

    Socket socket = (Socket) ModLoader.getPrivateValue(NetworkManager.class, manager, "networkSocket");

    InetAddress address = socket.getInetAddress();
    if(address != null) {
        String hostName = address.getHostName();
        String hostAddress = address.getHostAddress();  
            if((hostAddress.equals(SERVER)) || (hostName.equals(SERVER))) {

                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope I've given enough info, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still using private fields, but it turns out the problem was with obfuscation.